# jquery css how to retain position if you remove margin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, margin

I poked around and couldn't find this question in particular, if I missed it please kindly point me in the right direction.

**Purpose:** I'm in the process of creating a statistics reporting system for our website. When you first access it, it has a dashboard type of layout with overall statistics, and graphs to go along with it. I wanted to make it so that each individual set of stats/graphs can be moved around the page as you see fit, though it originally starts out in the center unless you move it. I'm using jQuery and the jQuery UI for this purpose.

**Problem:** For the initial view, I'm using `margin: 0 auto` to center the divs on the page. The first problem I had is when you go to drag it, you couldn't drag it to the left because of the margin that's set on it. I used the `draggable` event property `start:` to remove the `margin` property from the div. This fixed the problem with not being able to move it around as you would expect, but when you first begin to drag it, the removal of the margin forces the div to jump to the left side of the screen and you have to click it again.

Is there a way to prevent the "jump" and force the div to retain its current position while the margin property is being removed? Am I completely going about all of this in the wrong way? Any help is appreciated, even if you simply tell me to not go about it this way and figure something else out by yourself.

Thanks in advance!

jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.post("getStats.php", function (data) {
            var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
            var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data);

        }, 'json');

        var contPos = $("#statOverallCont").position();
        $("#statOverallCont").draggable({
            snap: ".snapTarget",
            snapMode: "both",
            containment: "body",
            drag: function () {
                $("#statOverallCont").css("margin", "");
                $("#statOverallCont").css("left", contPos.left);
                $("#statOverallCont").css("top", contPos.top);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

^I tried to grab its original position, and then attempt to change the position after the margin is removed. It didn't seem to do anything at all.

The DIV w/ Style:

```
<div id="statOverallCont" style="background-color: #dbdbdb; position: relative; display: table; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; clear:both; padding: 10px;border: 2px solid black" >
```

---

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Fata1Err0r/2mxqL38o/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drag function provides to parameters into it's callback. `event` and `ui`. The `ui` has a property called `ui.position` which contains `left` and `top`. When the drag strats, remove the margins, make the position of the element to absolute and set the position values taken from the parameters!

looks like this

```
drag: function (event,ui) {
     $("#statOverallCont").css("position", "absolute");
     $("#statOverallCont").css("left", ui.position.left);
     $("#statOverallCont").css("top", ui.position.top);
}
```

This should stick your element to the mouse when dragged.

**Update :**

You would need to update the css by removing the margin:0px auto; and then using the left property of the css set it to 50% so that it would be horizontally centered. This would allow you to drag the element without making it jump. **Btw the idea was grasped by Fata1Err0r** So win win situation. :D

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I just tried this out, but it's causing it to jump to the far upper-left corner of the document now, whereas before it was jumping to the far left-center.

Comment: Can you do a fiddle of your question! would be easier to find out the issue! :)

Comment: Definitely. Signing up on their site right now, give me a few mins and I'll post that link for you.

Comment: Yea, that's the original issue that I began with. :D It won't let you drag it to the left or right because the margin is set to "0 auto", which prompted me to remove the margin after it's being dragged.

Comment: Actually the issue can be fixed by using a left percentage in the css. I've no idea on the solution that you are developing bt is it possible to set a left percentage like 50% to get it centered?

Comment: I'm going to have multiple sets stacked on top of each other, so it doesn't need to be the center vertically, just horizontally. With that being said, I can go about it any way that works. Are you speaking about settings the margin-left or the position's left?

Comment: I'm referring to position left!

Comment: You're the man! :) I removed the `margin: 0 auto` from my CSS, and used `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%)` (translate was needed so the top-left corner wasn't the center point). This centers my DIV horizontally only and allows me to drag my box without it jumping. Update your answer with this solution and I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: Just an fyi, translate/transform blurred my text, so I had to figure something else out. I poked around further and figured out a decent solution, though it's still based on your suggestion, so update your own answer with it and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon the help of Dimal (thanks btw), this seems to be the best solution of going about it without using `margin` to center things, and without using translate/transform since it blurs text in Chrome.

jQuery:

```
//If you want to center it horizontally/vertically
jQuery.fn.center = function () {
    this.css("position", "absolute");
    this.css("top", ($(window).height() / 2) - (this.outerHeight() / 2));
    this.css("left", ($(window).width() / 2) - (this.outerWidth() / 2));
    return this;
}

//If you want to center it horizontally only
jQuery.fn.centerHor = function () {
    this.css("position", "absolute");
    this.css("left", ($(window).width() / 2) - (this.outerWidth() / 2));
    return this;
}

//If you want to center it vertically only
jQuery.fn.centerVer = function () {
    this.css("position", "absolute");
    this.css("top", ($(window).height() / 2) - (this.outerHeight() / 2));
    return this;
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    // grab stats from database and create graph
    $.post("getStats.php", function (data) {
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
        var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data);
    }, 'json');

    // Center it before displaying it so there is no visual jump
    $("#statOverallCont").centerHor().css("display", "table");

    $("#statOverallCont").draggable({
        snap: ".snapTarget",
        snapMode: "both",
        containment: "body"
    });

});
```

CSS:

```
background-color: #dbdbdb; 
display: none; 
clear:both; 
padding: 10px;
border: 2px solid black
```

I keep the div hidden while jQuery takes care of centering everything after the page loads up, then I make it visible again. This prevents you from being able to see it go from the left to the center.

Using position instead of margin fixes the problem with the jQuery UI draggable causing the div to jump when margin is removed.

[WORKING JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Fata1Err0r/2mxqL38o/3/)

---

**After this issue, I put it together in this way so that you can easily use it throughout your entire site, and future sites. Hope this helps someone else!**

center.js:

```
// We add a pos parameter so we can specify which position type we want

// Center it both horizontally and vertically (dead center)
jQuery.fn.center = function (pos) {
    this.css("position", pos);
    this.css("top", ($(window).height() / 2) - (this.outerHeight() / 2));
    this.css("left", ($(window).width() / 2) - (this.outerWidth() / 2));
    return this;
}

// Center it horizontally only
jQuery.fn.centerHor = function (pos) {
    this.css("position", pos);
    this.css("left", ($(window).width() / 2) - (this.outerWidth() / 2));
    return this;
}

// Center it vertically only
jQuery.fn.centerVer = function (pos) {
    this.css("position", pos);
    this.css("top", ($(window).height() / 2) - (this.outerHeight() / 2));
    return this;
}
```

In my `<head>`:

```
<script src="scripts/center.js"></script>
```

Examples of usage:

```
$("#example1").centerHor("absolute")
$("#example2").centerHor("fixed")

$("#example3").centerVer("absolute")
$("#example4").centerVer("fixed")

$("#example5").center("absolute")
$("#example6").center("fixed")
```

It works with any positioning type, and can be used throughout your entire site easily, as well as easily portable to any other site you create.